# Parse Simple Json Array in Play Framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, but I haven't found a way to do it. How do I go about parsing a simple json array: [1] as a List[Integer] or List[String] with the play framework Json Library in scala?

All of the examples I have seen in the documentation assume you are working with an object and are accessing an attribute in the object. When I try to parse the json I get an error:

```
jsonResult.as[List[String]]

JsError(List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsarray,WrappedArray())))))
```

Comment: Well... what is `jsonResult` exactly?

Comment: A WSResponse that was mapped to a json

Comment: For example `Json.parse("""[1, 2, 3, 4]""").as[List[Int]]` does what you ask.. but that depends entirely on what the JSON looks like in the first place. If you don't include that, no one can determine why you are getting that error.

Comment: Hmmm... That worked (minus the quotations cause I don't need them) but for some reason `.as[List[String]]` didn't work

Comment: That's because an array of Ints won't be read as Strings. `.as[List[Int]].map(_.toString)` will work. Otherwise you need to define your own `Reads[List[String]]` for it.